# How to hide android application folder from being shown in file explorer?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

My android application creates a folder in sd card which has some json files and html files inside.I want to hide this from the user so that the resource file remains safe.How to do this ??I saw that prefixing the folder name with "." will help.But this is not working for me.

Comment: Try to place `.nomedia` file inside that folder. See this [tutorial](http://android2know.blogspot.com/2013/01/create-nomedia-file.html) to learn more about hiding the private folder/file. You can download `.nomedia` file [here](http://www19.zippyshare.com/v/65285251/file.html).

Comment: Do not create that folder in sdcard or external memory to begin with. Create it in internal memory.

Comment: Agreed. Particularly on Android 3.0+, the complete and entire point behind putting files on [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is so that the user can access them. If you do not want the user accessing them, put the files on [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).